# Broken limb fixed with glue

Tags: figs

A few weeks ago, I snapped clean the end of a fig tree branch. Unsure on how to fix it, I put in back in place and secured it by gluing paper towel around it with glue (the glue was meant to stay on the outside, not get in the cut).

Here is a picture from today, with the paper towel removed.
[image]

The upper part seems to have dried out. Is there anything I can do to help this limb grow or it is lost at this point?

Comment: I would prune the limb below the cut. The tree will divert energy into growing new branches.